# Qual o tamanho da quebra de linha?

Tags: html, css

Olá, gostaria de saber se existe um tamanho padrão para a quebra de linha no HTML (`<br>`), se ela depende do tamanho da fonte que está sendo utilizada e como alterá-la.

Comment: O que você chama de tamanho da quebra de linha? Você sabe que além do tamanho da fonte, tamanho de onde está esta linha, tudo isto influencia? Podemos até questionar o que é uma linha. Ou você quer saber apenas abstratamente se um texto é longo demais, independente de como ele é apresentado na tela?

Comment: Eu quero saber como alterar o tamanho de uma linha em branco utilizando `<br>`.

Comment: o uso de `<br />` para controlar o layout é algo desaconselhável, tente ao invés disto manipular o padding, margin e height das suas `<div>`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pelo que entendi você quer aumentar o tamanho do br, como o line-height base é 100%, aumente conforme o necessário. O valor default do line-height é normal, ele é calculado pelo valor multiplicado pelo font-size.

Achei esse exemplo que utiliza div mas também funciona para o br e talvez te ajude a entender:

```
div { line-height: 1.2;   font-size: 10pt }   /* number */ 
div { line-height: 1.2em; font-size: 10pt }   /* length */ 
div { line-height: 120%;  font-size: 10pt }   /* percentage */
div { line-height: 12pt;  font-size: 10pt }   /* length */

br{
line-height: 200%;
}
```

```css
br {
  height: 1000px;
  width: 1000px;
  background-color: red;
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: block;
  line-height: 300%;
}
```

```html
<div>a<br>b<br>c</div>



<div>
  a
  <br>
  b
  <br>
  c
</div>
```

Como foi discutido é desaconselhável forçar a tag br e depende de cada navegador, porém existe uma solução cross browser

```
br {line-height: 200%; content: " "}
```

Comment: Tem opção em pixels também?

Comment: px acredito que não

Comment: Obrigado!! =DDD

Comment: Esta resposta está errada, por favor olhe a resposta do @MiguelAngelo

Comment: A resposta não está errada, mas tem uma parte controversa sobre o `br`. A parte que fala pra usar `line-height` para controlar a altura da linha está, de fato, correta.

Comment: Digo, no que tange ao `line-height` aplicado ao elemento `div`, como foi o caso do primeiro exemplo.

Answer (score 5):

A tag `br` não representa uma linha em branco, mas sim uma quebra de linha.

Com o código abaixo fica fácil verificar que nenhum atributo visual funciona com o `br`. Não dá pra alterar nem mesmo o `display`... <strike>nem nada.</strike>... eu estava errado, quase nada... variando em comportamento de navegador para navegador =)

```css
br {
  height: 1000px;
  width: 1000px;
  background-color: red;
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: block;
  line-height: 150%; /* no Chrome isso vai funcionar, caso não exista o caractere `\n` após a tag `br` */
}
```

```html
<div>
  a
  <br/>b<br/> c
</div>
```

Comment: Se você deixar <div>a<br>b<br>c</div>, aqui pelo menos eu consigo alterar o line-height do br

Comment: @haykou Em que *browser*? O exemplo acima não mostra mudança alguma no FF e Chrome. Será que é algo não padronizado?

Comment: O comportamento da formatação do `<br/>` varia de navegador para navegador, mas por exemplo: `br{display:block;margin:10px 0;}` já deve estragar a tua tese @MiguelAngelo :P +1

Comment: @haykou Que bizarro... realmente se não houver os caracteres `\n` o `line-height` é afetado.

Comment: @mgibsonbr eu utilizo tudo no codepen e com chrome.

Comment: @haykou De fato, seu exemplo atualizado funcionou no Chrome. Mas no Firefox, nenhuma diferença... Com certeza é algo não padronizado. :(

Comment: Isso do \n entendo como bug. A tag é "auto-fechante", não poderia mudar de comportamento com um elemento externo.

Comment: @mgibsonbr O comportamento é estranho demais... se o `br` tiver um caractere `\n` após ele ai o `line-height` não tem efeito, caso contrário, ai tem (no Chrome apenas) parece alguma bizarrice na implementação do Chrome.

Comment: @Bacco É como dizia à pouco, o comportamento varia de navegador para navegador. De acordo com a [regra](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/text-level-semantics.html#the-br-element), um `<br/>` não tem _box-model_ logo não deve afetar espaçamentos nem nada desse género... Mas nuns navegadores afeta, noutros não. Escusado será dizer que o `<br/>` serve o simples propósito de passar o texto que vem após ele para a linha de baixo, mais nada :)

Comment: @mgibsonbr, testei aqui sem o DOCTYPE do html e não funcionou no firefox/IE, já com o doctype o line-height deu certo.

Answer (score 3):

@haykou, note que o `<br />` tem o seu comportamento afetado por um simples `\n`, sem falar que o comportamento do css aplicado no mesmo difere muito de browser para browser, então é uma pessima escolha para montar o layout de uma pagina.

Você consegue encontrar citações sobre o que deve ser evitado quanto ao BR em diversas documentações

[Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/CSS/line-height):

> Do not use `<br>` to increase the gap between lines of text;
>
> use the CSS margin property or the `<p>` element.

[W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_br.asp)

> Tip: The `<br>` tag is useful for writing addresses or poems.
>
> Note: Use the `<br>` tag to enter line breaks, not to separate paragraphs.

Comment: postei este comentário como resposta, pois acredito que seja grande demais para um simples comentário inline, caso necessário posso apagar o mesmo.

Comment: Como você disse no comentário acima, concordo que é desaconselhável, não sei porque de fato alguém faria isso mas parece que outras pessoas já tentaram fazer o mesmo. Achei uma explicação melhor aqui http://stackoverflow.com/questions/899252/can-you-target-br-with-css

Comment: +1 Pelo comentário resposta. =P (extremamente relevante)... apesar te eu ter uma certa repulsa pela `W3Schools`, o que disseram está correto... mas se tivesse sido eu, ia procurar outra fonte que diz a mesma coisa só pra não dar mais PR pra eles.